# How to create binary column that compares a value to the total average of the same column such that if nb > average=1 & nb < average=0

Tags: sas, datastep

I'm working on an assignment & not allowed to use PROC SQL & must use DATA STEP or other PROCs. I have a dataset (Table A), & I'm trying to calculate a few things at the same time and I'm not any closer to my answer after spending few hours on r/sas, stackoverflow & YouTube. I need to create a binary column in Table A that =1 if the value in Column 3 >= the average of Column 3, but grouped by country. In PROC SQL it's quite simple:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE Earl.A AS

SELECT * ,
CASE WHEN A.new_cases > AVG(A.new_cases) 
THEN 1 ELSE 0
END AS Global_Average_Comparison
FROM Earl.A AS A
QUIT;
```

But in SAS data steps....I feel a bit like a deer in the headlights. I tried using a PROC MEANS, but that creates a new table & any attempt to merge it back to Table A brings back columns I dropped in a previous query that are irrelevant:

```
PROC MEANS DATA=EARL.A;
    BY country;
    VAR new_cases;
output out=means(drop=_type_ _freq_) mean=mean;
RUN;
```

I'm realllllllllly new to SAS data steps but well versed in SQL :( so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Forgot to add a GROUP BY country in PROC SQL...

Comment: Merging will NOT bring back variables you have dropped. Unless you are merging with the old dataset where the variables were not dropped.

Comment: How to add a summary statistic to your data set. https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/add_average_value_to_dataset.sas or look up DoW loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show the attempts to `merge`, but the process is pretty simple.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(123);
  do country = 'A', 'B', 'C';
  do _n_ = 1 to 100 + rand('integer',50);
    x = rand('integer', 25, 75);
    output;
  end;
  end;
run;

proc means noprint data=have;
  by country;
  var x;
  output out=means(keep=country x_mean) mean=x_mean;
run;

data want;
  merge have means;
  by country;

  above_average_flag = x > x_mean;

  * drop x_mean;
run;
```

[image]